# After reboot host goes into maintenance mode as I've the remote filesystems on LVM stack created over iSCSI LUNs - RHEL 7.x

Tags: linux, rhel

On RHEL 7.x I observe that the remote filesystems (SAN) does not allow host to come up after reboot. It enters maintenance mode and I've to comment out the entries in `/etc/fstab` to bring the host up and running.

I've few mount points `/etc/fstab` created over LVM stack which in turn is laid on iSCSI LUNs.

I guess this is due to systemd introduced from RHEL 7.x onwards. However I'm unable to get remote filesystems mounted after local filesystems. Let me know how/where to specify this ordering?

Answer (score 2):

Got this working by having `_netdev` as one of the mount options.
Also setting `use_lvmetad` in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` to `1` will bring the VGs/LVs online and mounts work without any issues. I do not observe the host going into
maintenance mode after reboot.